# How to get the angle that the turtle should move?

Tags: python

In python turtle.
lets say I have a point at (10, 12). and my turtle points at a random direction.
how can I get the degree that the turtle should turn to point at that (10, 12) point?

Answer (score 0):

To get the angle at which it should point:

```
import math

math.atan2(dest.x - curr.x, dest.y - curr.y)
```

it could be +- of the value or reversed in order, really depends on how everything is set up. play with it.

Comment: that is giving the angle with the X axis. how can I convert it to and actual degree? what i want is to know how to replace the turtle.goto() command with turtle.right() and turtle.forward()...  it can be as well turtle.left()

Comment: @Johndoe In that case you can just subtract the x values and Y values, treating negative as left for example and positive for right (and in the Y-axis case positive for up and negative for down)

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Johndoe I'm not really sure how it set up but for example: if your current X value is 10 and you want to move to a point where the X value is 4. You do: dest.x - curr.x which is -6 - You will translate that negative number as moving 6 points to the left.